# What AWS services do I need for Angular, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL projects?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, cloud

In researching the many AWS offerings and plans, I'm overwhelmed by the terminology and pricing around Docker, RDS, EC2, Beanstalk, and trying to wrap my head around it all. In the end, all we'd like is the cheapest way to host internal Angular 7+ apps that have a corresponding Spring Boot REST API which pulls from a PostgresSQL database. Of course each app/REST/DB stack should have a dev, test, and prod environment as well. Utilizing AWS, what is a good and cost-effective way to achieve these requirements?

Answer (score 4):

1. Angular - Use **S3** and CloudFront (Static content)
2. Spring Boot Rest API's - Use EC2, Beanstalk or **Lambda** (for serverless)
3. PostgreSQL - Use **RDS** or install it on EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you.  Any advantage of RDS over EC2 for the DB, and could the API live alongside the DB on the same EC2 to save costs?  Not sure if this is a good idea.  I'm a dev not an architect! haha.

Answer (score 2):

1. For Angular and Spring Boot Rest APIs, you can host both of them inside the EC2 machine.
2. For Database, You can host the postgresql servers on EC2 machines for dev and test environments and for production you can choose RDS.

Comment: Thank you, this helps clear it up a lot.  What's the advantage of RDS for a prod environment over EC2?

Comment: With RDS ,  you can scale easily scale up and scale down. They have a very nice interface which can be used for change configurations for the DB.